# How to normalize correlated variables for ANOVA

Tags: anova, normalization

I have [district](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Districts_of_England) level data about number of COVID-19 cases $X=\{x_i\}_{i=0}^n$ and frequency of newspaper reports about COVID cases $Y=\{y_i\}_{i=0}^n$. Here $n$ is the number of districts. I want to determine whether the districts are equally represented in the news. Here are the hypotheses:

$$\begin{align*}
H_0&: \text{all districts are equally represented in the news}\\
H_1&: \text{not all districts are equally represented in the news}
\end{align*}$$

From my understanding, there should a linear relationship between $X$ and $Y$ under null hypothesis. Hence, I performed one way ANOVA for the null hypothesis that
$$\frac{y_0}{x_0}=\frac{y_1}{x_1}=\cdots=\frac{y_n}{x_n}$$

I would like to know if the normalization step is statistically correct.

Comment: Do you mean causal or really casual? Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, don't think I get your comment. I used casual here in a sense that number of covid cases *causes* newspapers to report it. If this is misleading, I am happy to edit the title.

Comment: Well, I don't understand the title ... then english is a foreign language for me ...

Comment: I replaced *casual* with *correlated* in the title for clarification!